# How do i get the the user that created an user in graph

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have been reading the documentation on Microsoft Graph on [user properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0) and i can not find the "Created by user" property.

I have found the "Date of creation" property but does azure even register who created an user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a user, and the activity will show up in the Audit logs like below:

[image]

To **fetch the user that created a user,** you can make use of below query to filter Audit Logs:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com//v1.0/auditLogs/directoryAudits?&$filter=activityDisplayName eq 'Add user'
```

[image]

The `inititatedBy` is the user who created the user present in the `targetResources`.

Make sure to consent **`AuditLog.Read.All`** permission to perform the action.

**Reference:**

[Audit logs in Azure Active Directory - Microsoft Entra](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-audit-logs)